# F400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, release

I'm trying to create a release pipeline that will use Azure CLI to update a variable defined in Pipelines-> Library within a variable group.

I can update the variable directly from my computer using a PAT(saved within $PipelineAccessToken) I generated from my user account.

This it the script the Agent executes during the Release Pipeline:

```
$PipelineAccessToken | az devops login

az pipelines variable-group variable update 
  --org "https://dev.azure.com/[myOrganization]" 
  --project [myProject] 
  --group-id [groupId] 
  --name [variableName] 
  --value [newValue]
```

Azure Agent throws me this error

```
TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be the following:

As `PipelineAccessToken` is a pipeline variable it should be encased in brackets.

Furthermore, as I keep a PAT within that variable I have to enclose it in quotes so it gets piped as a string to `az devops login`.

Finally the solution is this:

```
"$(PipelineAccessToken)" | az devops login
```

Answer (score 0):

First up, try az devops login with the organization URL

```
  $pat | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/
```

Secondly, try setting the environment variable

```
#set environment variable for current process
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxx
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)